# Wine. Pokerstars Freezes with Pop Up Window

Tags: linux-mint, wine

I have just removed Mint 17.3 and installed Mint Mate 19.1 and installed the latest version of Wine Stable 4.0 from WineHQ. Pokerstars installed without error, updates and loads without error but when I log in, a pop up window titled "Online Software Terms of Service" appears with a biege shaded body which turns white after a second or two and the Pokerstars program is non-responsive. If I close the pop up, the program closes and I receive an error message. The program error details say:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x10588af0).
```

There is also a Register Dump, a Stack Dump and Backtrace which I do not understand. Should I post all that detail here? I have tried setting different versions of Windows using winecfg but these produce the same result. I have no other Wine utilities nor any other Windows software installed.

Comment: For starters, please [edit] your question to include a link to the other question you found.  (And please don’t use the word ‘‘forum’’; some people are sensitive about that.)

Comment: Thank you Scott. The other question was from a different site, sorry, and was not answered.

Comment: Did the software run with Mint 17.3 and which wine version?

Comment: Yes, Philippos. It ran under 17.3 using Windows XP but XP is no longer supported by Pokerstars.

Comment: After logging in to the Pokerstars website, (using Firefox, not the Pokerstars program), I completed the same popup window which now does not pop up when logging in to the game site so the software now runs without error.

Comment: @BobH1 thx that worked for me